# JAVA rxtxserial communication, response missing

Tags: java, serial-port

I slightly modifies the RXTX "Event Based Two Way Communication" (http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Event_based_two_way_Communication) so to be able to communicate with a device that is connected through a serial port.

From the documentation of the device, I know that the device should give a response to a command like "rs<cr><lf>", so before the writer loop I'm sending the command to the port.

Unfortunately, I'm not receiving any response from the device.

From the documentation of the device, the communication parameters are: 
9600bd, 8bit data, 1 Stopbit, no Parity

That I should have properly set in the connect method.

I guess I'm doing something wrong somewhere, is anyone able to point it out?

Thanks a lot!

```
public class TwoWaySerialComm{

public TwoWaySerialComm()
{
    super();
}

void connect ( String portName ) throws Exception
{
    CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
    if ( portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned() )
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
    }
    else
    {
        CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(),2000);

        if ( commPort instanceof SerialPort )
        {
            SerialPort serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,SerialPort.DATABITS_8,SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);

            InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

            (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
            (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out))).start();
            //System.out.println(serialPort.getBaudRate());
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
        }
    }     
}

/** */
public static class SerialReader implements Runnable 
{
    InputStream in;

    public SerialReader ( InputStream in )
    {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int len = -1;
        try
        {
            while ( ( len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1 )
            {
                System.out.println(buffer[0]);
                System.out.print(new String(buffer,0,len));

            }
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        System.out.println("exit reader");
    }
}

/** */
public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable 
{
    OutputStream out;

    public SerialWriter ( OutputStream out )
    {
        this.out = out;
    }

    public void run ()
    {
        try
        {                
            int c,c2 = 0;
            //String command = "rs<cr><lf>";
            String command = "rs\r\n";
            byte [] buff = command.getBytes();

            while(c2 < buff.length){
                this.out.write(buff[c2]);
                //System.out.println(c2 + ": " + buff[c2]);
                //System.out.println(new String(new byte[] {buff[c2]}));
                this.out.flush();
                c2++;
            }
            //System.out.println(buff.length);
            while ( ( c = System.in.read()) > -1 )
            {
                this.out.write(c);
            }                
        }
        catch ( IOException e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }            
    }
}

public static void main ( String[] args )
{
    try
    {
        (new TwoWaySerialComm()).connect("COM5");
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```